# Searching for an isolated list element

Tags: python, list

I need to find the index of an element in a list that is NOT a part of a specific sublist.

Here is an example:

```
List = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]
```

I have a function to determine if a list is a sublist of a larger list, but I don't know how to use that in this context, since the isolated `1` could be at the beginning or at the end of list. There will always be four consecutive `1`s and one isolated `1`.

Input is a list with four consecutive `1`s and one isolated `1`. All other elements are `0`.

The output should be the location(index) of the isolated element, in this example `10`.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about your question?
What is the input?
What is the expected output?

Comment: Do you mean you need to find out an element in the list that is surrounded by different elements (different value) on both side?

Comment: Yes, but the element could also be at the beginning or end of the list, so only have one surrounding element, eg [1,0,0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through each element between `1` and `length of list - 2` , both inclusive, and print the element that is surrounded by `0s` , and before the for loop check if for start elemnt , whether it is `1` and second element is `0` , or for end element whether it is `1` and second last element is `0` .

Code would be something like -

```
if lst[0] == 1 and lst[1] == 0:
    return 0
if lst[len(lst)-1] == 1 and lst[len(lst)-2] == 0:
    return 1
for i in range(1,len(lst)-1):
    if lst[i] == 1 and lst[i-1] == 0 and lst[i+1] == 0:
        return i
```

Use `xrange` for better memory usage in python 2.x

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly suited for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

def find_isolated_item(seq, search):
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(seq), key=itemgetter(1)):
        index, item = next(g)
        if item == search and sum(1 for _ in g) == 0:
            return index
...
>>> find_isolated_item([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0], 1)
10
>>> find_isolated_item([1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], 1)
0
```